# Why is sorting vector<wstring> using custom wcscmp and wmemcmp comparators much faster than default?

Tags: c++, string, performance, sorting, stl

It seems that sorting `vector<wstring>` using custom `wcscmp`-based and `wmemcmp`-based comparators is much faster (about 1000 ms) than the default behavior.

64-bit release build (VS2015):

```
Default1: 3304.39 ms
wcscmp1 : 2323.26 ms
wmemcmp1: 2300.11 ms

Default2: 3239.75 ms
wcscmp2 : 2303.37 ms
wmemcmp2: 2338.55 ms

Default3: 3293.73 ms
wcscmp3 : 2303.82 ms
wmemcmp3: 2313.88 ms
```

Compilable code:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Compare sorting a vector<wstring> with:
//  - default comparator
//  - custom wcscmp()-based comparator
//  - custom wmemcmp()-based comparator
// 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <string.h>     // wcscmp, wmemcmp

#include <algorithm>    // std::shuffle, std::sort
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <random>       // std::mt19937
#include <string>       // std::wstring
#include <vector>       // std::vector

#include <Windows.h>    // Windows Platform SDK

using namespace std;


//=============================================================================
//                        Performance Counter Helpers
//=============================================================================

long long Counter()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    ::QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    return li.QuadPart;
}

long long Frequency()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    ::QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li);
    return li.QuadPart;
}

void PrintTime(const long long start, const long long finish, const char * const s)
{
    cout << s << ": " << (finish - start) * 1000.0 / Frequency() << " ms \n";
}


//=============================================================================
//                           Performance Tests
//=============================================================================

bool CompareUsingWcscmp(const std::wstring& a, const std::wstring& b) noexcept
{
    // a < b
    return wcscmp(a.c_str(), b.c_str()) < 0;
}

bool CompareUsingWmemcmp(const std::wstring& a, const std::wstring& b) noexcept
{
    const size_t count = min(a.size(), b.size());
    return wmemcmp(a.data(), b.data(), count) < 0;
}

int main()
{
    // Build a vector of strings generated starting from "Lorem Ipsum"
    const auto shuffled = []() -> vector<wstring>
    {
        const wstring lorem[] =
        {
            L"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.",
            L"Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed",
            L"pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero,",
            L"sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna.",
            L"Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus.",
            L"Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et",
            L"malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede.",
            L"Mauris et orci. [*** add more chars to prevent SSO ***]"
        };

        vector<wstring> v;
#ifdef _DEBUG
        constexpr int kTestIterationCount = 1000;
#else
        constexpr int kTestIterationCount = 200'000;
#endif
        for (int i = 0; i < kTestIterationCount; ++i)
        {
            for (const auto & s : lorem)
            {
                v.push_back(s + L" (#" + to_wstring(i) + L")");
            }

        }

        mt19937 prng(1980);
        shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), prng);
        return v;
    }();

    long long start = 0;
    long long finish = 0;

    vector<wstring>  v1 = shuffled;
    vector<wstring>  w1 = shuffled;
    vector<wstring>  z1 = shuffled;

    vector<wstring>  v2 = shuffled;
    vector<wstring>  w2 = shuffled;
    vector<wstring>  z2 = shuffled;

    vector<wstring>  v3 = shuffled;
    vector<wstring>  w3 = shuffled;
    vector<wstring>  z3 = shuffled;

    start = Counter();
    sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    finish = Counter();
    PrintTime(start, finish, "Default1");

    start = Counter();
    sort(w1.begin(), w1.end(), CompareUsingWcscmp);
    finish = Counter();
    PrintTime(start, finish, "wcscmp1 ");

    start = Counter();
    sort(z1.begin(), z1.end(), CompareUsingWmemcmp);
    finish = Counter();
    PrintTime(start, finish, "wmemcmp1");

    cout << '\n';

    start = Counter();
    sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
    finish = Counter();
    PrintTime(start, finish, "Default2");

    start = Counter();
    sort(w2.begin(), w2.end(), CompareUsingWcscmp);
    finish = Counter();
    PrintTime(start, finish, "wcscmp2 ");

    start = Counter();
    sort(z2.begin(), z2.end(), CompareUsingWmemcmp);
    finish = Counter();
    PrintTime(start, finish, "wmemcmp2");

    cout << '\n';

    start = Counter();
    sort(v3.begin(), v3.end());
    finish = Counter();
    PrintTime(start, finish, "Default3");

    start = Counter();
    sort(w3.begin(), w3.end(), CompareUsingWcscmp);
    finish = Counter();
    PrintTime(start, finish, "wcscmp3 ");

    start = Counter();
    sort(z3.begin(), z3.end(), CompareUsingWmemcmp);
    finish = Counter();
    PrintTime(start, finish, "wmemcmp3");
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

P.S. I'm aware that `wcscmp` doesn't work for wstrings containing embedded nulls. But this is not the point of the question.

Comment: can you try again and compare when the `wstring` is allocated by `new`?

Comment: codekaizer makes a good point. it might be that fetching the buffer of wstrings is much more cache friendly

Comment: I have VS2017 and there the `wcscmp` version is 230-240 ms *slower*.

Comment: @codekaizer: Regardsless of how `wstring` itself is allocated, its contents will be on the heap (see the comment about long strings so you don't get Small String Optimization)

Comment: The machine code for the traits compare looks exquisitely optimized.  I tried to make your predicate just as inefficient, also digging up the size() and using wmemcmp().  Big surprise, it got a lot faster.  Very hard to see, this is a job for vtune.

Comment: Are you using `<Windows.h>` for timing functions?  You could make your code portable (more comparable between architectures) if you use the Standard Library's `<chrono>` instead.

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, that is the very reason I used `<Windows.h>`, for the high-resolution performance counters API. This code started from a Windows-only C++ code base that I was optimizing.

Comment: Can I just confirm that you *did* compile with optimisations enabled?  That's usually implied with [tag:performance], but always worth checking.

Comment: @TobySpeight As written in the question, I did a _Release_ build with Visual Studio, so optimization enabled.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a weakness of your library's `std::less<std::wstring>` (which is the default comparator for `std::sort()`).  For comparison, I made a portable version of your test:

```
#include <cstring>

#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// override this by compiling with (e.g.)
//   g++ -DITERATION_COUNT=1000
#ifndef ITERATION_COUNT
#define ITERATION_COUNT 200000
#endif

template<typename T>
struct time_printer
{
    T func;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const time_printer& p)
    {
        using Duration = std::chrono::duration<double, std::chrono::milliseconds::period>;
        auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        p.func();
        auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        Duration time_taken = end - begin;
        return os << time_taken.count();
    }
};

template<typename T>
time_printer<T> print_time(T fun) { return {fun}; }


int main()
{
    // Build a vector of strings generated starting from "Lorem Ipsum"
    const auto shuffled = []() {
        static const std::wstring lorem[] = {
            L"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.",
            L"Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed",
            L"pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero,",
            L"sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna.",
            L"Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus.",
            L"Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et",
            L"malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede.",
            L"Mauris et orci. [*** add more chars to prevent SSO ***]"
        };

        std::vector<std::wstring> v;
        auto const kTestIterationCount = ITERATION_COUNT;
        v.reserve(std::size(lorem) * kTestIterationCount);
        for (int i = 0;  i < kTestIterationCount;  ++i) {
            auto const suffix = L" (#" + std::to_wstring(i) + L")";
            for (auto const& s: lorem) {
                v.push_back(s + suffix);
            }
        }

        std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), std::mt19937{1980});
        return v;
    }();

    // name, function
    using comparator = std::pair<const char *, std::function<bool(const std::wstring&,const std::wstring&)>>;
    static const comparator comparators[] = {
        {" default", [](const auto& a, const auto& b){return a < b;} },
        {"std_less", std::less<std::wstring>{} },
        {"  wcscmp", [](const auto& a, const auto& b){return std::wcscmp(a.c_str(), b.c_str()) < 0;} },
        {" wmemcmp", [](const auto& a, const auto& b){return std::wmemcmp(a.data(), b.data(), std::min(a.size(), b.size())) < 0;;} }
    };

    static const auto passes = 3u;
    static const auto ncomp = std::size(comparators);

    std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>> inputs(ncomp * passes, shuffled);

    for (auto i = 0u;  i < inputs.size();  ++i) {
        auto pass = i % ncomp;
        auto round = i / ncomp + 1;
        std::cout << comparators[pass].first << " round " << round << ": "
                  << print_time([&]{std::sort(inputs[i].begin(), inputs[i].end(), comparators[pass].second);})
                  << std::endl;
    }

    // make sure they all sorted correctly
    return std::count_if(inputs.begin(), inputs.end(),
                         [](auto const& v){ return !std::is_sorted(v.begin(), v.end());});
}
```

Compiling with GCC 8, `-O3 -march=native` on Linux on an Intel i7-6700, I get best results with native or `std::wmemcmp()` and worst with `std::wcscmp()`:

```
default  round 1: 1734.87
wcscmp round 1: 2315.48
wmemcmp round 1: 1699.22
default  round 2: 1727.92
wcscmp round 2: 2305.81
wmemcmp round 2: 1635.28
default  round 3: 1719.26
wcscmp round 3: 2286.19
wmemcmp round 3: 1638.17
```

Comment: Thanks. I compiled your code with VS2015, and got slower numbers than with my original code (same hardware). Anyway, the default behavior is still considerably slower than custom `wmemcmp`/`wcscmp` (e.g. `default 3535.07, wcscmp 2728.27, wmemcmp 2805.93`).